# Entity Framework: Query Multiple Types

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-6, table-per-hierarchy

I have a EF6 code-first model with inheritance, for example:

```
[Table("Things")]
abstract class AbstractThing
{
   public int ThingId { get; set; }
   public string Color { get; set; }
}

class Car : AbstractThing
{
   public string Brand { get; set; }
}

class Balloon : AbstractThing
{
   public double Price { get; set; }
}

class Animal : AbstractThing
{
   public int LegCount { get; set; }
}
```

I use table-per-hierarchy, so my "Things" table will have the columns:

- ThingId : int
- Color : string
- Brand : string
- Price : double
- LegCount : int
- Discriminator : string

Now, I want to query for things that are of specific types, but this list of types is dynamic. E.g. I want all red things that are Cars or Ballons. In SQL that is quite easily done, as I could just compile a `where Discriminator in ('Car', 'Ballon')` clause.

The problem here is that, to my knowledge, the only way to filter by type in EF Linq2SQL is by using the .OfType method (or use specific collections). But then I get back the filtered list that only contains that type, I cannot use an 'OR' or 'IN' clause. I can't really figure out how to do this without explicitly querying every set and making a union:

```
var queryable = Enumerable.Empty<Thing>().AsQueryable();

if (typesRequested.Contains(typeof(Car)))
{
   queryable = queryable.Union(context.Things.OfType<Car>());
}
if (typesRequested.Contains(typeof(Balloon)))
{
   queryable = queryable.Union(context.Things.OfType<Balloon>());
}
if (typesRequested.Contains(typeof(Animal)))
{
   queryable = queryable.Union(context.Things.OfType<Animal>());
}
```

As in my actual model I have a lot more inherited types, this approach is not so feasible. The workaround I have in place now is to have a custom 'type' column that is redundant with the 'Discriminator' column, but this is error prone and creates boiler plate code.

Is there any other way to dynamically restrict a queryable to return only a specific set of types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems possible with EF Core: The 'Discriminator' property is now available as a **Shadow Property**. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance#configuring-the-discriminator-property )

i.e.:

```
var types = typesRequested.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
var filteredByType = context.Things.Where(tng => 
                 types.Contains(EF.Property<string>(tng, "Discriminator")));
```